# Hide Empty Subreport in SSRS2008 R2

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, subreport

I have added a subreport to my report. The aim is simply to hide the subreport  if there is no data in it.

NoRows property was mentioned on [this thread on Microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/3af7479e-8604-4e1a-af12-8170f0272c9d), but I guess it is for SSRS 2005 as the thread as quite old.

Isn't  there any obvious way to hide subreport if there is no data in it? I could hide the tablix in the subreport itself, but I also need to hide the row where subreport placed. To do this I need an indication whether the subreport has data or not in the main report.

Could you give a clue to sort this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem a year ago or so. My vague recollection of this:

The default behavior as I recall was that SSRS won't show the subreport if the datasets in the subreport return no rows. This accomplishes half of what you want, but doesn't let the parent report know whether to hide the subreport area or not. IIRC, the NoRows property only controls what will be shown in this case, but it's not easily checked at run-time to change other properties.

My final solution was to create a stripped down query in the parent report that would indicate whether or not the sub report would have any rows. I used this to control row and subreport visibility.

I suspect there's a more elegant answer...

Comment: I got similar reply from msdn forums before, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/3e2d45aa-a9b4-4c6c-b43a-e7e4d5222196. I will accept your reply as answer here. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I placed the subreport in a row of its own. Then I edited the rdl file in a text editor and set the row height to 0 (The designer will not let you do this).

With the row height at 0, the row is practically hidden, until the subreport gets data, at which point, the subreport determines the row height, and it all looks normal again.

An alternative to editing the rdl may be to set the height of the row in code, I haven't looked into that though.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and none of the answers worked for me. In my case I was converting a Crystal Report to an SSRS report and was using a sub-report that could occur for every group. This was fairly simple in Crystal Reports because you could suppress empty sections with a checkbox.

What worked for me in SSRS and was very clean was to add a subquery/CTE to my main report query that got a count of the number of rows that would be present in the sub-report data. For example:

```
SELECT CommonCriteria, Count(*) [RowCount]
FROM TableUsedInSubReport
GROUP BY CommonCriteria
```

Then just join this subquery/CTE to your main query on the common criteria. Once you have this it is very simple as you just right click on the far left of the row in the tablix and select Row Visbility. Then you use an expression such as...

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!RowCount.Value) > 0, false, true)
```

That way if there are any rows to display in the sub report it will display them and if there are no rows in the sub report it will hide it and not leave white space.

Answer (score 0):

AnarchistGeek

Hello,

I had just run into this issue myself. The ugly error along the lines of "Error: Subreport could not be shown" was really annoying me.

Solution:
To solve this, I simply nested the subreport within a rectangle and used an expression on the visibility for that rectangle like so.

ex.
=IIF(Fields!Field1.Value IS NOTHING,true,false)
(Field1 in my case was a returned data column from the parent report.)

Make your changes accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

i ended up using rectangle underneath the subreport - that way if subreport returns nothing, rectangle underneath it will control appearance of the cell - in my case I needed to grey out the cell if subreport returns nothing.

This thread gave me an idea [How to supress empty subreports in SSRS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006343/how-to-supress-empty-subreports-in-ssrs-2008?rq=1) but I did not even have to use expressions because by default SSRS won't render subreport if it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The more easy solution is:

> **Sanjay Kumar Rajarao** responded on 16 Oct 2013 12:15 AM Access sub report properties - visibility - show based on expression. Enter this
>   code:
>
> =IIF(RowNumber(Nothing)>0,False,True)

https://community.dynamics.com/gp/f/32/t/114129